# using html tags in xml document with namespace

Tags: html, xml

I want to display a simple line in my `xml` document using `html` namespace and tag `hr`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<documents xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<document>
    <title>doc1</title>
    <html:hr></html:hr>
    <text>data1</text>
</document>
<document>
    <title>doc2</title>
    <text>data2</text>
</document>
</documents>
```

But it shows document in browser like simple xml without any lines but with `<html:hr />` instead of line.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding "div" with styles (I created 1.html files with contents below and it worked in IE8.0.6001.18702)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<documents xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<document>
    <title>doc1</title>
    <div style='border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext .75pt;'>
        <html:hr/>
      <text>data1</text>
    </div>
</document>
<document>
    <title>doc2</title>
    <text>data2</text>
</document>
</documents>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work in my IE. but surprisingly it works in chrome lol. and even original code too.